# TypeScript POST API request error 400 - Bad Request

Tags: c#, html, typescript, post, .net-core

I've managed to solve a "quite easy" issue with **HTTP Post error responed 400** -> it **didn't call out my backend function** although the route was perfectly fine, my request also, so for future me I'd like to post resolve of this problem here.

Answer (score 0):

If you're POSTing from your frontend to .Net backend and send an array of objects, eg:

```
myMethod(cars: Car[]): angular.IPromise<string[]> {
    return this.uiBackendHttp
        .post('api/controller/Method', {
            Cars: cars
        });
}
```

where `Car` model contains properties, e.g. VehicleId, Weight, Model

you **can't expect array of cars** in your backend:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<string[]> Method(GetCarParameters param, CancellationToken token)
    {
        return (await _myService
                .MyBackendFunction(Cars[], token)).[//LINQ]

    }
```

**You've got to use `[DataContract]` model class:**

```
[DataContract]
public class GetCarParameters
{
    [DataMember]
    [Required]
    public Car[] Cars { get; set; }
}
```

and then your POST should look like:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<string[]> Method(GetCarParameters param, CancellationToken token)
    {
        return (await _myService
                .MyBackendFunction(param.Cars, token)).[//LINQ]

    }
```

Hope it'll help you also!

//EDIT:
Without DataContract it also works :)

```
public class GetCarParameters
{
    public Car[] Cars { get; set; }
}
```